# One stream analytics job vs multiple jobs

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

Performance-wise, is there a big difference between having one stream analytics job with multiple queries and outputs (Azure tables in my case) Vs. splitting these queries and outputs into multiple stream analytics jobs?

And if the difference is significant, how to determine which scenario best suits my needs?

The doc states that:

> Stream Analytics can handle up to 1 GB of incoming data per second.

but my concern is more about the processing of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things that will govern how far you can scale one stream analytics account:

- [The documented limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#stream-analytics-limits)
- How many Streaming Units you need to process your workload - see the FAQ at the bottom of [this page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/stream-analytics/).

Smaller windows processing less volumes will consume less units. Like many of the other PaaS services, the measured unit is esoteric and your mileage may vary, it's best to build a small sample for your use case and then make a prediction on how it will scale.

I certainly would not build a separate streaming job for every case, but you may need to find a way to "partition" your requirement, maybe by use case/feature, by business domain, consuming system, etc.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you! As usual with Azure, things look like a black box.